# Excel Validation - Have indirect list want List and/or Number

Tags: excel, vba

I have two cells with dependent list validation - I'm using INDIRECT to get the list/select box for the second cell based on the value of the first cell.

What I need to do is more complex and I'm struggling to find solution.

In cellA, if value1 is selected, cellB should have list1 (I can do this now)
But if in cellA value2 or value3 is selected, cellB should require any number - not a list value.

Basically I need a list validation in cellB in one instance but in another, I need a number validation - any number.

Can anyone help with this ?  Appreciate it.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include any VBA or the formula(s) you are using in `CellA` and `CellB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they only way to do this automatically is to use VBA to apply the correct type of validation.

The following example, which you cant just drop in as is, should give you some clues to what you need to do. This code would be placed in the worksheet code module for the sheet you are working with.

You can use the macro recorder to get the code to generate the validations you need.

If you can update your question with your code and formula you have I might be able to modify this a little more to your needs.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' Target is a reference to the Cell(s) that have changed.

    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    ' We only care about this cell (CellA)
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case "needalist"
            ' remove any existing validation and add the list validation to $B$1 (CellB)
            With Sheet1.Range("$B$1").Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=$C$1:$C$7" ' Formula1 Can contain a formula
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        Case "needanumber"
            ' remove any existing validation and add the number validation to $B$1 (CellB)
            With Sheet1.Range("$B$1").Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateWholeNumber, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="1", Formula2:="10" ' Formula1 is min, Formula2 is max
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        Case Else
            ' Catch Everything
            Sheet1.Range("$B$1").Validation.Delete
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I've been thinking of.  I'm a developer but I've never bothered to learn excel.  I'll give it a try tomorrow at work (since no ms/excel at home) and let you know how it goes.  Cheers!

Comment: Just to follow up... I was able to make the required mods and this solution worked exactly as I needed.  Thanks NickSlash!